# What's the equivalent of Typescript's "key in EnumType" in Flowtype?

Tags: typescript, enums, flowtype

Typescript allows me to write such code:

```
export enum ActivityType {
  FREERIDE = "FREERIDE",
  SKI_TOUR = "SKI_TOUR",
}

const activityDesctription: {
  [key in ActivityType]: string
} = {
  [ActivityType.FREERIDE]: "Freeriding",
  [ActivityType.SKI_TOUR]: "Ski-touring"
};
```

The `in` expression gives me very strict type-safety, i.e. activityDesctription has to contain definitions for each member of enum, not less, not more. It also generates appropriate index operators.

**How do I do `in` expression in Flowtype?**

Comment: There're no "mapped types" in flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Updated answer

If you want `activityDescription` to be *exactly* the same keys as `ActivityType` and to complain when you're missing some, use `$ObjMap` ([docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-objmap)). [Flow try](https://flow.org/try/#0MYewdgzgLgBAgsKBLAbkqBPAKhgDgUxgF4YBvAKBhgDEAlAUXtoEkARegLhgCI7GX23ADSUYAZQDSzAPpYA8gFVaXbpJnylw8gF9y5TAXFQATkjABzAGoBDADYBXQiQA8lgHwAKSwEpibmNCmFuSgkLDWiKjoGKz4EMCmuMjgXAAkcgBGAFYAsta4zgb4IABm8JFomDgEQkZBVnaO-iQUVADaCMiV2Hj4AHR8TGz0ALpcAOQYIOMi7Z1RVb19arKKtGMw41AAFkgQMHswJfZgMzpAA)

```
const ActivityType = {
  FREERIDE: "FREERIDE",
  SKI_TOUR: "SKI_TOUR",
}

type StringValue = <V>(V) => string
const activityDescription: $ObjMap<typeof ActivityType, StringValue> = {
  [ActivityType.FREERIDE]: 'yo',
  [ActivityType.SKI_TOUR]: 'this is fun',
}
```

## Old answer

You can use `$Keys<typeof obj>` which will extract the keys of the obj. [Docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-keys), and [Flow try](https://flow.org/try/#0MYewdgzgLgBAgsKBLAbkqBPAKhgDgUxgF4YBvAKBhgDEAlAUXtoEkARegLhgCI7GX23ADSUYAZQDSzAPpYA8gFVaXbpJnylw8gF9y5UJFgBDRKnQZW+CIgBOSXMnBcKVANoASCfgwQAPJgIQADN4UzRMHAIAPgBdLmg7MABzHWIyUVcEZHDsPHwAOj4mNno4nmobfHw7ABMkZK03LLMIvPy1WUVaMtUAayQAWigQAFdEpMaqGGqbEBsuAHIZuYWdAG4gA).

UPDATE: As noted in the comments, this solution does not throw compile errors when keys of `ActivityType` are missing from `activityDescription`.

```
const ActivityType = {
  FREERIDE: "FREERIDE",
  SKI_TOUR: "SKI_TOUR",
}

const activityDescription: {
  [$Keys<typeof ActivityType>]: string
} = {
  [ActivityType.FREERIDE]: "Freeriding",
  [ActivityType.SKI_TOUR]: "Ski-touring",
  error: 'error' // flow errors here
};
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, this still does compile in Flowtype:
_
const activityDesctription: {
  [$Keys<typeof ActivityType>]: string
} = {
  [ActivityType.FREERIDE]: "Freeriding",
};
_
Typescript doesn't allow this.

Comment: I'm confused, what's unfortunate about this?

Comment: I want to get a compile error. Let's say activityDesctription contains a description for each ActivityType enum. If I add a new entry to ActivityType I want to make sure I add an entry to activityDesctription. Typescript would tell me about missing entry at compile time by using "in" operator. The code that you proposed would compile just fine and the missing entry would be detected only at runtime.

Comment: Ah, I understand! FTFY. :-)

Comment: Ah, perfect! Flowtype has some powerful stuff it's just feels obfuscated :)

Comment: As is often the case with powerful tools... yeah I've been working with Flow for over a year now and I'm still figuring stuff out.